# Object doesn't support property or method 'map' in chart.js

Tags: asp.net, wcf, chart.js, wcf-rest

I am trying to display a bar chart using chart.js and ASP.Net. When I write hard coded values in my AJAX code then it works fine but when I call a WCF service then it shows error.

**Error**
[image]

**Here's my HTML code:**

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:50984/Dashboard.svc/getChartData", function (labels) {
                var labeldata = labels;
                var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart1");
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"],
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "Today's File",
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                data: [56, 4, 23],
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            });
```

The above code works fine but when I change one line to read data from WCF then it gives error:

Change

```
labels: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"],
```

To

```
labels: labeldata,
```

**Here's my WCF code:**
[image]

And Interface part of code:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "getChartData", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        string getChartData();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Ok first I followed this example:

> https://codepedia.info/chart-js-asp-net-dynamically-create-line-chart-with-database-ms-sql-using-jquery-ajax-c-example/

And then this one:

> https://www.justcodeweb.com/dynamic-line-chart-in-asp-net-from-database-using-chart-js/

In both cases AJAX call goes to "error" method instead of "success". The only change I made in code is that I removed SQL Server part and wrote hard coded values. If I call my WCF directly from browser using following URL then it returns JSON. But when same is called in AJAX then it goes to "error" method.

> http://localhost:54480/Dashboard.svc/getNewChartData

*JSON*

> ["['2017-05-07','2017-05-06']","[531,131]"]

Don't know what to do now.

Comment: The `labeldata` variable is assigned the value of the `labels` parameter. What gets passed to the `function`. I am guessing it is not an `Array`.

Comment: It is being passed JSON string as shown in WCF code above.

Comment: well strings don't have a map method. It needs to be an array.

Comment: I tried to follow two examples from the web but in both cases the AJAX call is going into that error method instead of success. I don't know what to do now I have tried everything.